# iOS web app: prevent screen dimming/locking

Tags: ios, web-applications

How do I prevent iOS from dimming and/or locking the screen of my WEB app?
This is for a WEB app, so any native code suggestion would not apply.
The WEB app would run without user input and I'd like to avoid iOS automatically dimming/locking the screen (without turning the setting off in the global settings).

Is there a way for a WEB app to tell iOS not to dimm/lock the screen?

If the above is not available, is there any third party app that would monitor the system and turn off screen locking/dimming when a given web app is running?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a new alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not turn off the autolock from a WebApp. Also there is no way for any thirdparty app to detect this, since apps can not really run in the background.