# Can a mobile web app prevent an android phone from screen locking?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-website

A native Android app has ways to do this: [How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically)

But my question: **What about a web app running on an android device?**

Aside:
In iOS, according to [iOS web app: prevent screen dimming/locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399990/ios-web-app-prevent-screen-dimming-locking) there isn't any way to... which is too bad. If someone knows otherwise, share your knowledge please!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps at some time in the future [this JavaScript API will be supported](http://www.w3.org/TR/wake-lock//):

```
windows.screen.keepAwake = true;
```

Until then, you would have to wrap a `WebView` in an app that can [bind to JavaScript events](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).